# Running NOOBS on a used SD card

Tags: sd-card, setup, noobs

I had an 8 GB SD card with Arch ARM installed. I couldn't get the WiFi to work, so I wanted to reinstall via NOOBS. Since then, I've deleted all of the Arch files and extracted the NOOBS ones in their place, which didn't work. I've also messed around with `gparted` (formatting everything to FAT32), and cleared every partition using `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdbN` for every `N`.

Every time I plug in the power cable, all I see is the red `PWR` LED turning on. Any idea why it's not booting, and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

it's not booting because you've cleared up the partitions and messed around with parted.

you may fix this by downloading a NOOBS installation image and following the instruction about how to copy it to your SD card.

Comment: I've done that (formatting everything to FAT32 again), but it didn't work. I notice that there's a very small partition at the start (< 100 MiB), which seems fixed in place. Could that be causing problems?

Comment: @JamesWood if you do everything correctly, you don't have to format anything and it does not matter, if there's a formatted partition or not or two or more.

Comment: I don't understand. Step 2 of the NOOBS installation is to format the SD card, so doing the installation right implies having formatted something.

Comment: @JamesWood oh, they must have changed something since the last time I've read, nowadays you're supposed to delete all partitions, then create one single large FAT partition and unzip the contents of the archive there. Or use raspbian image, that does not care about previous formattings and existing partitions.

Comment: Okay, no worries. I've fixed it now by just copying over an image I had on another card via `dd`. It's not strictly an answer to my original question, but I'll add it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had another Pi SD card lying around, so I copied the image from there onto my computer (`sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=img.img`), unmounted the SD card (`sudo umount /dev/sdb?*`), inserted the broken SD card and copied the saved image to it (`sudo dd of=/dev/sdb if=img.img`).